# Ending a loop when fscanf reads a certain value from a text file

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a program that reads a character and a float from a text file and then saves these values to a variable. 
The text file is formatted in this manner:

```
S 15.24
G 28.00
S 56.90
H 90.00
0
```

I'm attempting to have the character be read and then have it run through a switch to do a few calculations based on which character comes before the float(all S values are grouped together, all G values are grouped together, etc)
To have it go through all the lines available, I'm using a while loop that terminates when the read character reaches the 0 at the end of the list. 
Just for testing purposes I'm having the program print "Done" when it exits the loop. However when I run the program, it runs through every character and prints it properly to the terminal until its printed the values before 0. once it reaches the 0, the program doesn't do anything else, but it doesn't print "Done" like I assumed it should.
This is the code I'm using:

```
int main()
{
int s_num,g_num,h_num,S,H,G,n_total;
float amount,s_total,s_sum,g_sum,h_sum;
char char_name;

FILE*Input; 
Input = fopen("Input.txt","r");
FILE*Output;
Output = fopen("Output.txt","w+");


char_name = 1; //Just using 1 as a way to make the while loop occure

while(char_name != '0')
{
    fscanf(Input,"%c%f",&char_name,&amount);
    switch(char_name)
    {
        case 'S':
            printf("S,%f\n",amount);
            break;
        case 'G':
            printf("G,%f\n",amount);
            break;
        case 'H':
            printf("H,%f\n",amount);
            break;


    }



}
printf("done");

return 0;


}
```

(disregard the unused values, those are to be used in the actual program)

What changes would I need to make to get the loop to terminate once it reaches 0?

Comment: Try replacing `fscanf(Input,"%c%f",&char_ name,&amount);` with `fscanf(Input,"%c%f%*c",&char_ name,&amount);` or `fscanf(Input,"%c",&char_ name);fscanf(Input,"%f%*c",&amount);`

Comment: The first one appeared to have worked. Could you explain the significance of the *c?

Comment: `%*c` does the same thing as `%c` except that it dosen't store the result anywhere. `%*c` scans a character and discards it. In your case, it will scan the newline character from the end of each line and discards it.

Answer (score 1):

The following code:

```
 fscanf(Input,"%c%f",&char_name,&amount);
```

will fail to read a float upon hitting the last data line in the file. The switch statement is not needed. Use an if statement to check if the first char is '0' and either break or read the floating point number and print both the character and number.

```
while (TRUE)
{
    fscanf(Input,"%c",&char_name);
    if (char_name == '0')
        break;
    fscanf(Input,"%f",&amount);
    printf("%c,%f\n",char_name,amount);
}
```

Comment: Using this code seems to throw the program into a loop that prints ,0.00000000 over and over.

Comment: @Ezri The idea is correct though. I might not be reading the carriage returns and line feeds or something.  Aren't you using an IDE for debugging? You can execute your code a line at a time and examine the values of the various variables. Try that and tell me how it goes. If all else fails, I will have a closer look at it. Is this a homework?

Answer (score 0):

Using `fgets()` and then parsing the line is the best way to go.  But using `fscanf()`, recommend:

1. Change format so white-space is ignored.  otherwise `'%c'` will take on white-space values

   ```
   // fscanf(Input,"%c%f",&char_name,&amount);
   fscanf(Input," %c%f",&char_name,&amount);  // add space
   ```
2. Check the return value from `fscanf()`.  do not use values `char_name,amount` unless the return value from `fscanf()` indicates those values were indeed filled.

   ```
   int cnt = fscanf(Input," %c%f",&char_name,&amount);
   switch(cnt) {
      case 1: Handle_OnlyCharName(); break;           // Candidate only "0" line
      case 2: Handle_BothCharNameAndAmount(); break;  // OP's switch(char_name)
      case EOF: Handle_IOErrorOrEndOfFile(); break;   // No more data
      default: NeverShouldGetHere();
   }
   ```

Comment: Will the `default case` ever get executed? Can scanning a `%c` fail(When not `EOF`)?

Comment: @Cool Guy "Will the default case ever get executed?"  Hmmmm, maybe - when white-space precedes the EOF or IO error.  Have to test.